# Getting real time values from an excel feed

Tags: c#, java, c

Hello
My application from the stockbroker has this button called "Start excelfeed" which opens an excel file and then updates the incoming prices in realtime. I want these prices extracted into my application (Java), but after several tries with jxl and poi ive found out it only extracts the values which occurred last time i saved the excel files. Are there any possible ways to extract these prices in real time? I'm not sure which method theyre using to feed the excel file, except their app is written in C#.

Comment: Is it possible to programmaticly save the document, possibly by using COM or Javas Robot Class?

Comment: Did not understand the question... Are you trying to get unsaved data from Excel? Or While reading close and open the xls document in a loop. Make sure that you have the recent file with your program.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to get unsaved data.

Comment: Since the data is updated every second it might lead to heavy cpu load? If it's possible to save programmaticly, it should be possible to bring the data also?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the VBA code behind the "Start excelfeed" button by hitting Alt+F11 ... Then you can check how the excel macro taps into the data source und try to adapt that in Java

**[EDIT]**
@Zico Sorry then I got you wrong. In that case I'd try to automate it via the Java Robot Class like user489041 suggested or you could fire up wireshark and try to snoop around the network traffic

Comment: +1 for figuring "application from stockbroker" is an Excel spreadsheet :)

Comment: @pmg Don't ask me how many Excel-"Applications" I have to see every day ... If C is nuts 'n bolts and Java is Lego then VBA is friggin' Play Doh ;)

Comment: The excelfeed button is only a feature on a relative large program, from the stockbroker. Tried Alt+F11, but no VBA is used.

Answer (score 1):

They are using the DDE technique and you should use excel automation to pull data from excel into your app.

Answer (score 0):

In the old days, we used DDE links. Chances are your stockbroker addin uses precisely that.

Chances of using DDE from java are pretty slim (close to zero) because it is windows specific. However, possibly there are other methods involved (like COM components or TCP/IP connection). I'd suggest you get the values from teh stockbroker source like the Excelfeed, instead of going through Excel.

Of course, the problem with that is that you won't get help from the vendor of the Excel addin. If things are like they were 8 years ago, they are making tons on your buying the Excel addin and don't really want to help you program against that :)

Answer (score 0):

Worst case, you could use the Java Robot class to create the Excel spreadsheet, save the Excel spreadsheet as a CSV file, then read the CSV file from your Java program.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with solutions like [Obba](http://www.obba.info). Obba allows to access a Java virtual machine running the "Obba Server" directly from Excel.

For your problem, you have to "create" your application from the spreadsheet (load the jar, create an object representing you app - e.g. launching it in a separate thread). Then you can feed the app from Excel... - In this case, Excel is to some extend the "control program" of your app. However, if you start the Obba Server process manually, the process will keep on running if you close and re-open Excel.